How to change the tick labels from decimals to integer in ContEx library?
Hello fellow learners.
I am creating charts in my Elixir project, using a Elixir library ContEx - https://hexdocs.pm/contex/Contex.html
I have a barchart. Below is the code i have used to create this chart.
    dataset = [
      ["Sage", scores.sage],
      ["Scientist", scores.scientist],
      ["Leader", scores.leader],
      ["Warrior", scores.warrior],
      ["Mother", scores.mother],
      ["Entrepreneur", scores.entrepreneur],
      ["Perfectionist", scores.perfectionist],
      ["Servant", scores.servant]
    ]

    options = [
      custom_value_scale:
        Contex.ContinuousLinearScale.new()
          |> Contex.ContinuousLinearScale.domain(0, 56)
          |> Contex.Scale.set_range(0, 56),
      colour_palette: ["ffdfae"],
      data_labels: false,
    ]


    Contex.Dataset.new(dataset)
    |> Contex.Plot.new(Contex.BarChart, 550, 280, options)
    |> Contex.Plot.to_svg()
    |> elem(1)


Now how should i change the y axis decimal ticks to integer. I have found the below function. But this doesn't seem to provide the answer that i want.
https://hexdocs.pm/contex/Contex.BarChart.html#custom_value_formatter/2
Is this the function that i need to use? I didn't find any other methods which will do this. Please help me to solve this.
How should i change the y axis ticks to integer?

I do not think this is possible. The ContinuousLinearScale has floats "baked in" to the source code. You could copy the code from this module (in deps/contex/lib/chart/scale/continuous_linear_scale.ex) and make your own module that uses integers, e.g. DiscreteLinearScale. I have not read the whole module so I do not know how difficult it would be. To start, just find all floats and change them to integers. That might be enough to make it work.

Thanks. I found all the floats and changed them into integers. The ticks has been changed into integers. Thank you so much for the help

You should close this question if it does not need attention. I will post what I wrote as an answer, for completeness.

I do not think this is possible. The ContinuousLinearScale has floats "baked in" to the source code. You could copy the code from this module (in deps/contex/lib/chart/scale/continuous_linear_scale.ex) and make your own module that uses integers, e.g. DiscreteLinearScale. I have not read the whole module so I do not know how difficult it would be. To start, just find all floats and change them to integers. That might be enough to make it work.
